# Qt 5.0 with MingW?

Tags: c++, qt, mingw

I'm not seeing any Qt 5 library that will work with MingW [in this page](http://qt-project.org/downloads).

If I want to use Qt 5 with MingW, and develop software on Windows, what are my options?

Comment: [Download the repository](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt) and build it yourself? Or just the zipped source from the same page you linked to.

Comment: here is a link on building Qt5: http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_5_from_Git

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download QT source from that page and build it with MinGW!

Comment: There is a pretty comprehensive guide for doing that in the docs, too. It still is annoyingly complex, lots of prerequisites need to be installed, like Perl, Python *and* Ruby, if I remember correctly... I hope they get around to releasing MinGW binaries some time soon.

Comment: I just built Qt 5.0 x64 at work for Visual Studio 2010. In order for the build to complete I needed to install perl and python. For this I used Active State perl and python.